# How to put external js API in cocos creator?

Tags: javascript, html, cocoscreator

I am just wondering how to put another js API library( in my case, i want to put the smartfoxserver javascript API library) in cocos creator? because what i did in cocos2d-js, i just need to add it in project.json, and I am wondering if i can do same way in cocos creator or another way?

thank you in advance

reference question from:

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-put-another-js-api-library-in-cocos-creator/32598

Answer (score 3):

good day

you can use module exports

```
var x = {
/*
your stuff
*/
};
module.exports = x;
```

then access it from other scripts using

```
var externalScript=require("name of the script with module.exports");
```

cheers

Answer (score 0):

i just scan the smartfoxserver.  it  use the websocket  that  is fine  just  drag  an drop the  SFS2X_API_JS.js to the project  and  require it  and  init  it  maybe  you  would use  window.xxx  to  set  the  connection handler as global value